# Android. Как установить фоновое изображение скачанное из Firebase хранилища

Tags: android, firebase

Только знакомлюсь с Firebase.

**Задача: скачать изображение из Firebase хранилища и установить его как фоновое изображение.**

С горем пополам удалось скачивать изображение. Делаю это с помощью этого кода:

```
        //Скачиваие файла
        // Получаем доступ к Хранилищу
        FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        // Создаем ссылку на рут
        StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://имя моего бакета");
        // Создаем ссылку на файл 
        StorageReference pathReference = storageRef.child("image/20170703_142533.jpg");
        //Android (Java)

        // Создаем пустой временный файл (оболочку) на устройстве, куда будет загружен скачиваемый файл
        File localFile = null;
        try {
            localFile = File.createTempFile("images", "jpg");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Вызываем метод getFile() и устанавливаем слушатель успеха, который срабатывает в случае успеха процесса скачивания
        pathReference.getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) 
            {
                // Файл был скачан
                Log.d("TAG_LOG", "Файл был скачан"); //Пишет в лог
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) 
            {
                // Ошибка
                Log.d("TAG_LOG", "Ошибка"); //Пишет в лог
            }
        });
```

Исходя из того, что в логах пишется `Файл был скачан`, я понимаю, что всё работает.

Но вот **куда этот файл скачался и как его установить как фоновое изображение никак не пойму.**